# Why jQuery add() method seems not to return a jQuery object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Consider that you want to add an ajax functionality to many links on your page.

```
<a href='http://domain/purchase/car' class='purchase'>Car</a>
<a href='http://domain/purchase/bag' class='purchase'>Bag</a>
<a href='http://domain/purchase/laptop' class='purchase'>Laptop</a>
```

and

```
<a href='http://domain/sell/car' class='sell'>Car</a>
<a href='http://domain/sell/bag' class='sell'>Bag</a>
<a href='http://domain/sell/laptop' class='sell'>Laptop</a>
```

Now you might define some variables to refer to these groups of links in your JavaScript code:

```
var purchaseLinks = $('.purchase'),
    sellLinks= $('.sell');
```

Well, enough story ;).

You can look at the problem in [this](http://jsfiddle.net/saeedneamati/q573N/) fiddle and [this](http://jsfiddle.net/saeedneamati/q573N/1/) one.

According to [jQuery's add() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/add/), the return value is a **new jQuery object**. And again, AMAIK inside a function handler that is attached to an event of a jQuery object, `this` referes to the DOM element.

Why by using `add()` method, `this` of the handler function refers to the `document`? I don't understand it. I can't match my knowledge to make a logical perception. In other words:

```
jQueryObject1.click(function(){
    // Here, $(this) is the jQuery object
});

jQueryObject2.click(function(){
    // Here again, $(this) is the jQuery object
});

jQueryObject1.add(jQueryObject2).click(function(){
    // Here $(this) refers to the Document, why?
    // I think jQueryObject1.add(jQueryObject2) should equal jQueryObject3
});
```

UPDATE:

Thanks for your answers. I again refer readers to [Live is Deprecated](http://liveisdeprecated.com/) page, so that everyone can improve.

Comment: If you're interested in the full details of what actually happens inside jQuery, I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem in your fiddle is the use of `.live()`. The jQuery docs state:

> Chaining methods is not supported. For example, `$("a").find(".offsite,
>   .external").live( ... );` is not valid and does not work as expected.

Fortunately for everyone, the [`.live()` method is deprecated](http://liveisdeprecated.com), so you don't have to worry about stuff like that anymore. You can use `on` instead and take advantage of event delegation.

---

**Update** (following the comment by @Esailija)

This is what actually happens. You call jQuery here:

```
var purchaseLinks = $('.purchase');
```

That results in a jQuery object, which has a `selector` property. You then call `.add()`, which in turn calls the internal `pushStack` method:

```
return this.pushStack(isDisconnected(set[0]) || isDisconnected(all[0]) ? all : jQuery.unique(all));
```

The [`pushStack` method](http://james.padolsey.com/jquery/#v=1.7.2&fn=pushStack) creates the new jQuery object. It gets called with only one argument. Here's the relevant parts of the method (note that `name` and `selector` are both `undefined` in our case):

```
function (elems, name, selector) {
    // ...

    ret.context = this.context;

    if (name === "find") {
        ret.selector = this.selector + (this.selector ? " " : "") + selector;
    } else if (name) {
        ret.selector = this.selector + "." + name + "(" + selector + ")";
    }

    // Return the newly-formed element set
    return ret;
}
```

Also note that `this.context` is now the document (since your original jQuery object didn't specify a context, the highest possible context is assumed).

So the newly formed element set doesn't have a `selector` property, and has the document as its context. When we then call `.live()`, jQuery simply calls `.on()` like this:

```
jQuery( this.context ).on( types, this.selector, data, fn );
```

And there we can see the problem. The context is the document, and there is no selector, so the event handler gets bound to the document. The above line in our case is effectively this:

```
jQuery( document ).on( "click", function() {
    //Your event handler
});
```

And you can see this by the fact that your `alert` is triggered by clicking anywhere in the document, not just on the links.

The moral of the story? Stop using `.live()`!

Comment: `.live` supports chaining in jQuery versions where `.on` is supported. Though some methods can change the `.selector` property which gives unexpected results when you use `.live` after them. But chaining in general is not issue.

Comment: @Esailija - Thanks, I didn't know that. I've updated my answer with the full details of what happens.

Answer (score 0):

```
var purchaseLinks = $('.purchase'),
    sellLinks= $('.sell');
purchaseLinks.add(sellLinks).on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert(this.href);
});
```

Nothing wrong with `.add()` change `.live()` to `.on()`.

http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/q573N/5/

Comment: The is this a problem of `live` method? See my fiddles and click the links please.

Comment: Maybe it's because of your name. But it's not me ;).